# Optimizing Sequential Mouse Actions on Canvas: Seeking Efficient Delays in JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I have a canvas with different objects drawn inside it that I need to drag. The canvas is drawn, so I have no direct access to the elements. I am using an "image searching" algorithm for interaction. However, when drag actions occur too closely in time, they do not work correctly, possibly due to overlapping.

The code below successfully moves three objects by waiting for a specified number of milliseconds after each drag action. The challenge is that the waiting time is predetermined, and the required wait seems to vary based on the PC's available resources. Additionally, I need the execution to be as fast as possible, so waiting for an extended period is not an option.

```
var canvasElement = document.querySelector('body > canvas');

function simulateMouseEvent(eventType, x, y) {
    canvasElement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(eventType, { clientX: x, clientY: y }));
}

function performClickAndDragAction(FoundX, x_temp, y_temp) {
    simulateMouseEvent('mousedown', FoundX, 626);
    simulateMouseEvent('mousemove', x_temp, y_temp);
    simulateMouseEvent('mouseup', x_temp, y_temp);
}

if (canvasElement) {
  
    performClickAndDragAction(67, 47, 591);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        performClickAndDragAction(186, 160, 591);

        setTimeout(() => {
            performClickAndDragAction(305, 255, 591);
        }, 1000); 

    }, 1000); 
} else {
    alert('No canvas.');
}
```

I attempted to use Promises to address this issue, but it seems I may have misunderstood their functionality. The current code doesn't work as intended; it appears as though each action is performed with zero waiting time, causing them to overlap, and often only one action is executed.

Below is the modified code using Promises. The code has been tested using the Developer Console.

```
var canvasElement = document.querySelector('body > canvas');

function simulateMouseEvent(eventType,x, y) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        canvasElement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(eventType, { clientX: x, clientY: y }));
        resolve();
    });
}

function performClickAndDragAction(FoundX, x_temp, y_temp) {
    return simulateMouseEvent('mousedown', FoundX, 626)
        .then(() => simulateMouseEvent('mousemove', x_temp, y_temp))
        .then(() => simulateMouseEvent('mouseup', x_temp, y_temp));
}

if (canvasElement) {
    performClickAndDragAction(67, 47, 591)
        .then(() => performClickAndDragAction(186, 160, 591))
        .then(() => performClickAndDragAction(305, 255, 591))
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error: ', error);
        });
} else {
    alert('No canvas.');
}
```

Any suggestion on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: You can add something like `.then(new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)))` to the `performClickAndDragAction` function to add a one second delay between calls to `performClickAndDragAction`. This will only work if you chain the calls like you do now.

Comment: Not sure how this is an improvement of the first code: "The code below successfully moves three objects by waiting for a specified number of milliseconds after each drag action. The challenge is that the waiting time is predetermined, and the required wait seems to vary based on the PC's available resources. Additionally, I need the execution to be as fast as possible, so waiting for an extended period is not an option." I'm missing somthing? Thx :)

Comment: This is not a solution. If you use my suggestion, you'll make the `Promise`s approach work the same as the `setTimeout` approach. Currently, the `Promise`s approach doesn't do anything, is the same if you're just calling those functions without wrapping everything in `Promise`s.

Comment: The point is to avoid using a predetermined intervals. Otherwise I would have used just setTimeout and not the Promises